# Import muliple excel file into sql server database

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have multiple excel files, each file have data for different tables.In these excel files first row contains column name.

Is there any way to run these all in one go.

I tried to import using sql server import but it is taking one file at a time.

Comment: What about writing a script that would loop through all the input files?

Comment: yes, I thought for that but dont have much idea of  run for loop in sql server

Comment: The construct is very simple... For instance `WHILE (<logical condition>) BEGIN <your logic> END ;`. You may wish to google a little bit on this.